# login form POST parameters in Backbone JS

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I am trying to build a sign in system using Backbone JS.

Here is a brief description of the API:

HTTP Method: POST
Request type: JSON

Parameters: 
a) user[email]
b) user[password]

Response:
1)- Success:
    a- :status => OK
2) Failure:
    :status => :unauthorized

I'm trying to use

```
this.model.save({
    email: this.$el.find("#email").val(),
    password: this.$el.find("#password").val()
},
```

but the problem is that the parameters are of the type user[email] and user[password].

How do I solve this?

Comment: this.model.save({
      'user[email]': this.$el.find("#email").val(),
      'user[password]': this.$el.find("#password").val()
    })

Answer (score 1):

```
this.model.save({
 'user[email]': this.$el.find("#email").val(), 
 'user[password]': this.$el.find("#password").val() });
```

make sure the values are not empty.